# recommended way of storing date and displaying them in client

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm working on a chat app and I want to display the date and time of the each message sent

my flow is like this

1) when user clicks on send button, I'm calling server method with the message as param

In the server method

1) I'm getting the date using `var d = new Date();`
 which is storing something like 
`"Sat Feb 28 2015 17:33:20 GMT+0200 (EET)"`

In every browser I want to display this time according to their timezones,

how to do this?
I've `moment` package installed too.

Comment: You should get the date via `new Date().getTime()` or `Date.now()` which stores it as a number.

Comment: @Bergi, okay in the client , how to display according to their timezone

Comment: You wouldn't even need momentjs for that, every browser does just that by default: `new Date(storedvalue).toString()`

Comment: thanks for the help, can you post it as answer, so I can close the question

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting the date using `var d = new Date();` which is storing something like `"Sat Feb 28 2015 17:33:20 GMT+0200 (EET)"`

I'd recommend to use numeric timestamps instead. You can get them using [`new Date().getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) or [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

> In every browser I want to display this time according to their timezones. I've `moment` package installed too.

You don't need moment.js for that, though it might help with formatting. After you have constructed the date from the timestamp using `new Date(storedValue)`, the default output methods like [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) will use the local timezone anyway.